# Upgrading Ubuntu without touching the MBR

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, truecrypt

**TL;DR:**  Is there a way of doing a `do-release-upgrade` and being sure that it won't touch the MBR?

**Background:**  I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my laptop.  I have Truecrypt's bootloader in the MBR as I use it to encrypt the Windows partition.  If I bypass Truecrypt's auth at boot time, I can pass control to GRUB which sits on the Ubuntu partition.  This might be an unusual config, but this is how I like it :-)

**The problem:**  When I upgraded to a newer release, the MBR was overwritten with GRUB, meaning that I had to use a Truecrypt rescue disk to recover my original configuration.  I'd like to avoid this if possible.  Now I need to upgrade, and I'm nervous about kicking off an automated process that will cause the same problem.

Comment: in which case, please assume that this question was asked a few weeks ago... I'll need to know this again when 14.04 comes out.

Comment: Besides the general policy to put 1 question in 1 thread, your "side question" is very interesting. Please do open another question for that and edit your post accordingly (delete it here). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your apt sources from `raring` to `saucy` from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and issue `sudo apt-get update`. Then issue `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`.(you can use your favorite dependency resolver instead of APT-Get, however, they are known to cope badly with full distribution update)

Comment: It really was that simple!  Although this method is apparently [not recommended](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/192164), it worked perfectly for me, just like a Debian upgrade.  Don't know why I never thought of trying it, but thank you!